# Jump to App Settings from in app

Tags: ipad

Is there a way to provide a UIAlertView, and if the user clicks a certain button, that it takes them to the app settings (in the general iPad Settings menu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, no way. If you want it, file a bugreport and if enough people want something like this, Apple might implement it.